# how do i print range of a sequence except one with while loop in c

Tags: c, while-loop

I want to print 1-1000 without 998. This code prints up to 997 then it stops. What is the problem with this code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() { 
    int n =1;
    while(1){   
        if(n==998){
            continue;
        }
        printf("%d\n",n);
        n++;
        if(n>1000){
            break;
        }   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what should while(1) do?

Comment: @StimpsonCat Infinite loop I guess

Comment: yes and when should it terminate? This does not make sense.

Comment: When `n` reaches 998, you stop incrementing it, so it never reaches 1000. Use a for loop: `for (int n = 1; n <= 1000; n++) { if (n != 998) printf(“%d\n”, n); }`.

Comment: @StimpsonCat Maybe the `break` was added for that purpose...

Comment: @Gerhardh that does not make it any better

Comment: Please stop writing code until you learn how to use your debugger, (or even printf).  If you cannot debug, you cannot program.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that we never increment `n` once we reached the `998`

One solution would be to move `n++;` above the `if (n == 998) continue;` or vice versa, i.e.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    while (1) {

        n++;
        if (n == 998)
            continue;
        if (n > 1000)
            break;

        printf("%d\n", n);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is with your condition:

```
if(n==998){
  continue;
}
```

It won't increment the variable "n".

One way to fix it is the following code:

```
if(n==998){
  n++;
  continue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your solution stuck at 998 because you always execute continue to enter the next iteration without incrementing your value. Here is a much more simple, compact form:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { 

    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
        if (i == 998) {
            continue;
        }
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once `n` is 998, you jump to the next iteration of the loop without incrementing `n`.  This results in an infinite loop where nothing is being output.

Rather than using `continue` when `n` is 998, instead you can print if it is *not* 998:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() { 
  int n =1;
  while(1){ 
    if(n!=998){
      printf("%d\n",n);
    }

    n++;
    if(n>1000){
       break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This can be simplified further by using a `for` loop rather than an infinite `while` loop with the exit condition inside:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() { 
  int n;
  for (n=1; n<=1000; n++) {
    if(n!=998){
      printf("%d\n",n);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The middle-testing while loop in the question is pretty clumsy compared with a `for` loop.  This works and is approximately the minimal change that will work, but the extra 4 lines of loop control compared to a `for` loop are fairly ugly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Agreed.  I kept the changes minimal to make it easier for the OP to see what needed to be changed.  I'll add a section on cleaning up the loop logic.